# Qlik Sense and Smartsheet

Tags: qliksense, smartsheet-api

Can we connect online interface of Qlik Sense to Smartsheet? If yes, can the data be refreshed automatically in regular intervals? If no, is there a suggested alternative to Smartsheet that can connect to Qlik and refresh automatically.

Looking for a platform wherein we could create custom data input templates for multiple stakeholders and connect it to a Qlik Sense dashboard

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Qlik Sense, but a quick look at the Smartsheet docs shows that there's a data connector available that enables you to connect Smartsheet with Qlik Sense: https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/odbc-docs/#qlik-sense.

Additionally, a quick Google search for `Qlik Sense Smartsheet` returns several results from `https://community.qlik.com` that describe others trying to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Smartsheet provide full REST API https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#authentication-and-access-tokens. In qlik Sense you need prepare connections by using rest api connector https://help.qlik.com/en-US/connectors/Subsystems/REST_connector_help/Content/Connectors_REST/Create-REST-connection/Create-REST-connection.htm .

First make post request, extract token. Next use token to make your get request to the data.